# Como implementar roles de usuario en Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-auth

Estoy utilizando Firebase para la autenticación de mi proyecto Flutter con el paquete [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth). Necesitaría crear roles de usuario.

Para esto he leído que me sería útil utilizar [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#python) pero no se como utilizarlas en Flutter. La documentación solo explica para otros lenguajes.

Otra solución que había pensado es crear en mi base de datos un registro de "administradores" y ahí agregar los uid. Sin embargo, si pudiera aplicar estos roles directo desde la autenticación de Firebase me ayudaría a administrar las reglas de lectura y escritura. ¿Cómo puedo implementar los roles con Fireabse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo no se puede utilizar roles de usuario en Firebase con Flutter. La solución que le he dado yo es guardar los ID en la base de datos y desde ahi asignarle a cada uno un rol, de la siguiente forma:

```
{
   'IDUSER1':0,
   'IDUSER2':0,
   'IDUSER3':0,
   'IDUSER4':1,
   'IDUSER5':1,
   'IDUSER6':2,
   'IDUSER7':0,
}
```

Como ejemplo, usando el 0 para usarios comunes, 1 para moderadores y 2 para administradores.